# Why does PostgreSQL service restart during autovacuum

Tags: postgresql

We developed an application and back-end of this application is PostgreSQL. I got an error like DB connection lost from my application, When I am checking it, i saw the following log in my PostgreSQL log

```
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [1676-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [1676-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [1620-1] postgres@db_prod FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [32367-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [7601-569] postgres@watchtower_db_prod FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [1689-2] LOG: autovacuum launcher shutting down 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [7598-1] postgres@db_prod FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [30875-1] postgres@stg FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [12717-1] postgres@stg FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [12695-1] postgres@stg FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [7956-1] postgres@stg FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [23056-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19989-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19993-1] postgres@stg FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19988-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19976-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19990-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19681-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [20474-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [19669-1] postgres@stg FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [13315-1] postgres@stg FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command 
2018-03-07 06:35:14 UTC [1686-1] LOG: shutting down 
2018-03-07 06:35:16 UTC [1686-2] LOG:  database system is shut down 
2018-03-07 06:35:17 UTC [2819-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-03-07 06:35:16 UTC 
2018-03-07 06:35:17 UTC [2819-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled 
2018-03-07 06:35:17 UTC [2818-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections 
2018-03-07 06:35:17 UTC [2823-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

My question is why does a PostgreSQL restart happen during this auto vacuum process?

Comment: "*received fast shutdown request*" means someone actively shut down the service.

Comment: This has nothing to do with autovacuum.